# Mock HttpClient.SendAsync to return response with Content not null

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy, httpcontent

I'm trying to mock `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);` but my `response.Content` is always `null`.

My mock looks like...

```
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
httpResponseMessage.Content = new StringContent("test content", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
A.CallTo(() => httpClient.SendAsync(A.Fake<HttpRequestMessage>(), CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage));
```

it seems like it is properly mocked but the response.Content is null but the status code - for example - reflects what I set in the test.

I'm sure one of you guys out here have encountered this problem, all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because that's not a valid `HttpResponseMessage`. It's missing some headers if not something else too. Why don't you just create a mock `DelegatingHandler` class? It's the simplest way IMHO

Comment: There's a really good library out there created specifically to simplify mocking of the HttpClient. It's called WireMock, you should give it a try. https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely the call to `SendAsync` isn't being matched. I see you configured your fake to respond to

```
A.CallTo(() => httpClient.SendAsync(A.Fake<HttpRequestMessage>(), CancellationToken.None))
```

But it's very unlikely that your production code is passing a first argument that compares as equal to the `A.Fake<HttpRequestMessage>()` argument you have here.

Did you instead mean

```
A.CallTo(() => httpClient.SendAsync(A<HttpRequestMessage>.Ignored, CancellationToken.None))
```

(or equivalently `A<HttpRequestMessage>._`)?

You can read about how arguments are matched on the [Argument constraints](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints) page. Specifically, see how to match any argument at the [Ignoring arguments](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#ignoring-arguments) subtopic.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I forgot `.Ignored`